# Why my app does not go through ProviderListener in a simple counter?

Tags: flutter, state, counter, state-management, riverpod

I am testing riverpod but it doesn't work.

I just want to have the typical counter that when it reaches two it goes to another screen. The counter works but does not launch the second screen or go through the ProviderListener.

```
void main() {
 runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

final _counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CounterStateNotifier>((ref) {
  return CounterStateNotifier();
});

class CounterStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<int> {
  CounterStateNotifier([int count]) : super(count ?? 0);

  void increment() {
    state++;
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final int _counter = watch(_counterProvider.state);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: ProviderListener<StateNotifier<int>>(
        provider: _counterProvider,
        onChange: (context, _counter) {
          if (_counter == 2) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => ScondScreen(),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          context.read(_counterProvider).increment();
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I haven't found a ProviderListener example to guide me.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel sem velit. Sed condimentum convallis sollicitudin. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque maximus congue porttitor.

Comment: any errors ?  I just saw that `ScondScreen()`. Is it mistake or not ?

Comment: not working with no errors. it does nothing when it reaches two and I can continue counting.

Comment: ok but your screen is named `ScondScreen()` ? . Shoudnt it be `SecondScreen()` ?

Comment: if typo i couldnt have executed it ? . `code class ScondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ScondScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key); `

Comment: ok. Try to log something inside of that `onChange` and check if that `if` is passing or not. If the `counter` changes than it seems its a problem of Navigator.

Comment: yes you are right, if a typo you shoudnt be able to execute it but its good to eliminate obvious things than after trying to figurout something for hours, realize that indeed it was some typo.

Comment: putting logs, it never gets inside the `onchange`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved changing to `ChangeNotifier`:

```
void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

final _counterProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<CounterChangeNotifier>((ref) {
  return CounterChangeNotifier();
});

class CounterChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  CounterChangeNotifier([this.count = 0]);

  int count;

  void increment() {
    count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final counter = watch(_counterProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: ProviderListener<CounterChangeNotifier>(
        provider: _counterProvider,
        onChange: (context, counter) {
          if (counter.count == 2) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute<ScondScreen>(
                builder: (_) => ScondScreen(),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '${counter.count}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          context.read(_counterProvider).increment();
          //counter.state++;
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as I personally didnt use it before I give my shot to help by discovering this new thing for me.

Here I can see:
https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#providerlistener

that code is

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ProviderListener<StateController<int>>(
    provider: counterProvider,
    onChange: (context, counter) {
      if (counter.state == 5) {
        showDialog(...);
      }
    },
    child: Whatever(),
  );
}
```

the difference is that in example there is `counter.state == variable` and in yours `counter == variable` but if onChange doesnt even fire than maybe this is the case

```
ProviderListener<StateController<int>>
```

and in your case its based on stateNotifier not controller ( I guess its not the same)

```
ProviderListener<StateNotifier<int>>
```